# Xsession error while logging in.

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

Today I could not login into my Ubuntu Mint 18 Cinnamon. The xsession error occures. The error is:

/etc/mdm/Xsession: 1: export: [i]: bad variable name

I understand, that there is something wrong with my environment variables. But I do not know how to find bad one. What is "**[i]:**"? May be this is the key?

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. '[i]' was the part of locale definition and was situated in /etc/xprofile. I have deleted this string, saved and reboot. And that's all.

Why this string appeared in this file, I do not know. All I can say, I have added es_EC locale and then deleted it.

I found very useful info in the following article: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=193917

Thanks for all, and be careful!